# Unable to import sumCashBy using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: corda

IntelliJ IDEA started highlighting errors in some of my import statements that worked previously. This is not unexpected as net.corda.finance is still in the "incubating" stage.

I am working in Java.

Corda Release: 3.3

Noticed this change on github: https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/4700

So I made what I thought are the necessary changes...

//Old

//import static net.corda.finance.utils.StateSumming.sumCashBy;

//New

import static net.corda.finance.contracts.utils.StateSumming.sumCashBy;

...but I'm still getting an error.  I am sure I must be overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 2):

@Kid101 put me on the right track by trying StateSumming.sumCashBy(contractState)

Once I did that IntelliJ recognized I needed to add:

```
net.corda:corda-finance:3.3-corda
```

...to the classpath.  If I allowed IntelliJ to add it from the context menu the error reappeared every time gradle refreshed.  So I added:

```
cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
```

...to the build.gradle file under the dependencies section.  No more errors with my import statement:

```
import net.corda.finance.utils.StateSumming;
```

...and no issues calling the sumCashBy method.

Answer (score 0):

The change you mention is in Corda `master` branch, In `CashTests.kt` you can see how `sumCashBy` is imported, `import net.corda.finance.contracts.utils.sumCashBy`.

In `corda/release-V4-branchpoint` import is still `net.corda.finance.utils.sumCashBy` i.e. the change has not made in yet to `V4`.

Try to build the project again.

If using Java, try: `StateSumming.sumCashBy(contractState)`

Answer (score 0):

You should import a dependency package.

You add below to `build.gradle` and refresh your IntelliJ project.

```
dependencies {
    ....
    cordaCompile "$corda_core_release_group:corda-finance-contracts:$corda_core_release_version"
    ...
```