# Unable to import sumCashBy in Corda v4.3 branch [Kotlin]

Tags: corda

Question is pretty self explanatory. I've tried the suggestions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54601576/unable-to-import-sumcashby-using-intellij-idea) and also [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/4738)

To summarise, added :

```
 cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-finance-contracts:$corda_release_version"
```

To build.gradle and attempted to add the following import.

```
import net.corda.finance.contracts.utils
```

It is unable to import it. Is there another helper to do the following:

```
 val received = tx.outputs.map { it.data }.sumCashBy(input.owner)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing like this

```
import net.corda.finance.contracts.utils.sumCashBy
```

Comment: It is strange as it fails to locate finance in net.corda.finance... I can see the JAR/Classpath in intellij.

Comment: Make sure you're adding the dependency to the desired module